# IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer, how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am currently working on amazon products dataset and want to fill NaNs in column named "amazon_category_and_sub_category". I want to do it with modes of categories for each manufacturer:

```
modes = X_train.groupby(by="manufacturer["amazon_category_and_sub_category"].apply(lambda x : np.nan if pd.Series.mode(x).size == 0 else pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
```

I calculate these modes based on `X_train` values, but now I want to do the same thing for `X_test`. As i understand i should use modes from `X_train` values. Before i do that, i need to check if there is a new manufacturer in test sample :

```
nans_test = X_test["amazon_category_and_sub_category"].isna()

nans_test = X_test.loc[nans_test, "manufacturer"].isin(modes.index)
```

After that, when I try to set values for `nans_test` mask :

```
X_test.loc[nans_test, "amazon_category_and_sub_category"] = modes[X_test.loc[nans_test, ["manufacturer"]]].to_numpy()
```

I get an error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Can you explain pls why is this happening and how to fix it?

UPD: I want to first fill NaNs with modes, where it is possible and later define a value for NaN's which left

I checked indeces for both `X_test` and `nans_test` but they look the same way.
Tried to google an error but it feels that each situation has it's own special bug in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need chain both conditions tested by `&` for bitwise `AND` and for mapping use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m1 = X_test["amazon_category_and_sub_category"].isna()
m2 = X_test["manufacturer"].isin(modes.index)

nans_test = m1 & m2

X_test.loc[nans_test, "amazon_category"] = X_test.loc[nans_test, "manufacturer"].map(modes)
```